# Can a Burn address send transactions?

Tags: transactions, bsc

I found a transaction on bscscan in which a burn address sends some tokens.

The transaction: https://bscscan.com/tx/0xa03e1803eff745227865f4f58dc50847b1afc1c5628a323603db01a2e5bcaf06

I'm new here. can anyone explain that to me? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a token is created, the from address is always the Burn address. Think of it as the "birth place" for that token.

But in general, NO, a burn address cannot send transactions. A burn address is an address that nobody owns the Private Key Off and thus nobody can verify transactions from.

This was a CREATION event rather than a 'asset transfer'

Comment: Great answer, but in this particular case, the function being called is actually `burn()` so I can only assume that for some reason the token's burn function also mints tokens? Not sure since the code isn't open source. I'd probably stay away

Comment: the "burn address" (0x0...0dEaD) and the 0 address (0x0...00) are 2 different things. What @AvocadoChocolate is referring to (the "brith place" of tokens), is the 0 address. Now they're both address no one has control over, so sending tokens to one of those addresses would result in the token being burned. In this particular case, the `burn()` function seems to have been coded wrong (intentionnally or not, but the token contract isnt verified so i'd guess its intentionnal) and ends up sending tokens from the burn address to the owner using ERC20s `transferFrom` method instead of burning them.

Comment: there is a private key for 0x0...0dead address but to find it you need a quantum computer